How does the Warlock's invocation Gaze of Two Minds interact with a creature with the Invisible Condition?
The warlock's invocation Gaze of Two Minds (GoTM) provides a fascinating ability to use another creature's senses and potentially cast spells as if the warlock is in their space.
However, there seems to be a lack of specificity regarding how the spells interact when they come from "the recipient" of the GoTM.
Gaze of Two Minds (emphasis mine)

You can use a Bonus Action to touch a willing creature and perceive through its senses until the end of your next turn. As long as the creature is on the same plane of existence as you, you can take a Bonus Action on subsequent turns to maintain this connection, extending the duration until the end of your next turn. The connection ends if you don’t maintain it in this way.
While perceiving through the other creature’s senses, you benefit from any special senses possessed by that creature, and you can cast spells as if you were in your space or the other creature’s space if the two of you are within 60 feet of each other.

I am presenting a scenario in which the rules as written in the 2024 Players Handbook could leave players and DMs scratching their heads;
Invisible Condition compromised on a Rogue who took the Hide action. A warlock uses GoTM with a Rogue, who later successfully hides. Then, the warlock casts Eldritch Blast from the hidden rogue's position.
The rules of Hide state in part

The condition ends on you immediately after any of the following occurs: you make a sound louder than a whisper, an enemy finds you, you make an attack roll, or you cast a spell with a Verbal component.

Here, the rogue did nothing to compromise his/her position.
However, returning to the description of "the spell is cast as if it were in the other creature's space" COULD suggest that the attack originated from there, thus compromising the rogue's Invisible condition.

Related: Can a familiar maintain invisibility while delivering a touch spell?

Related: How does the Warlock's invocation Gaze of Two Minds interact with the Unseen rule?

The Warlock is the caster, so the creature retains invisibility.
RAW, this is pretty straightforward. When you Hide

you have the Invisible condition...

but

The condition ends on you immediately after any of the following occurs: you make a sound louder than a whisper, an enemy finds you, you make an attack roll, or you cast a spell with a Verbal component. (emphasis mine)

So, the hidden creature must be the caster of the spell in order to lose the Invisible condition.
Gaze of the Two Minds allows the Warlock to cast spells from the hidden creature's location.

... you can cast spells as if you were in ... the other creature’s space...

But, the hidden creature does not cast the spell. So, RAW the hidden creature retains the Invisible condition. However, so long as the spell has a perceivable effect,

Awareness of Being Targeted. Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature doesn’t know it was targeted by the spell.

anyone might perceive the spell's point of origin, become suspicious, and investigate by taking the Search action. So, they may discover the hidden creature, regardless.
Notably, the Warlock does not retain the Invisible condition if using the Gaze of the Two Minds to cast a spell in another creature's space.

Yup, RAW this isn't even casting it through the other creature (like when a familiar delivers a touch spell for its master).  Narratively, sure maybe the magic comes out of them.  Hmm, if someone wanted to counterspell, would they see the linked creature making somatic gestures or hear the verbal component? RAW they have to see something "as if you" were in that space doing the casting.  But that's narratively hard to explain without having the target actually come close to casting the spell, which would break invis.  I can see now why they asked, although RAW is clear.

Someone would need to be within range of the Warlock to counterspell. I imagine the Warlock is still the one making somatic and verbal components, and the origin of the spell is transposed to the other creature.

(For my previous comment, I was thinking the question was about the spell Invisibility (3rd), which ends on casting a spell.  But no, it's about becoming non-hidden.  Certainly you'll draw attention to the spot, and if there's a bright light as the magic forms before shooting off, that might reveal someone hiding in shadows.  e.g. don't cast Sunbeam or Dawn from the rogue who's only hidden because of shadows, not opaque cover.)

you can cast spells as if you were in your space or the other creature’s space if the two of you are within 60 feet of each other.  - How far does the as-if go?  The magic is forming there, not from your actual position, so shouldn't someone be able to counterspell it there?  They would have to "see a creature within 60 feet of yourself casting a spell with Verbal, Somatic, or Material components", so if you want to rule that they can't CS unless they're in range of the warlock's real position, that there isn't actually a warlock there casting, and narratively it doesn't look that way.

I don’t think so. But, it’s a doubled edged sword. If only the warlock can be counterspelled, then he can’t exploit the Gaze to avoid it from someone closer to him.

Indeed, that's why it's an important balance question how far the as-if extends.  (I don't see an obvious RAW right answer.)  And for this question about hiding, narratively what people are actually seeing if the warlock casts this way for Fireball (a bead streaks...) or Sunbeam (bright light from a bead in your hands, which you can re-activate on later turn.)

Again, for Fireball, I would say that the Warlock points, but the bead streaks from the other creature's space, like through a wormhole or something.

Another food for thought, is whether a familiar on the invisible Rogue's shoulder throwing a rock at someone reveals the Rogue. If that doesn't, then obviously this also doesn't. If that does, then why doesn't this do?
